# Extract objects from JSON array with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON data like bellow

```
[{
    "CurrencyDenomination_JSON": "[{\"PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID\":1,\"CurrencyDenomination\":2000,\"NoofCurrency\":2,\"Total\":\"4000.00\",\"IsNote\":true},{\"PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID\":2,\"CurrencyDenomination\":500,\"NoofCurrency\":2,\"Total\":\"1000.00\",\"IsNote\":true}]"
}, {
    "CurrencyDenomination_JSON": "[{\"PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID\":1,\"CurrencyDenomination\":2000,\"NoofCurrency\":5,\"Total\":\"10000.00\",\"IsNote\":true},{\"PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID\":2,\"CurrencyDenomination\":500,\"NoofCurrency\":2,\"Total\":\"1000.00\",\"IsNote\":true}]"
}, {
    "CurrencyDenomination_JSON": "[{\"PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID\":1,\"CurrencyDenomination\":2000,\"NoofCurrency\":5,\"Total\":\"10000.00\",\"IsNote\":true},{\"PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID\":2,\"CurrencyDenomination\":500,\"NoofCurrency\":5,\"Total\":\"2500.00\",\"IsNote\":true}]"
}]
```

and I want to extract value from it and expect bellow data

```
[{
    "PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID": 1,
    "CurrencyDenomination": 2000,
    "NoofCurrency": 2,
    "Total": "4000.00",
    "IsNote": true
}, {
    "PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID": 2,
    "CurrencyDenomination": 500,
    "NoofCurrency": 2,
    "Total": "1000.00",
    "IsNote": true
}, {
    "PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID": 3,
    "CurrencyDenomination": 200,
    "NoofCurrency": 2,
    "Total": "400.00",
    "IsNote": true
}, {
    "PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID": 4,
    "CurrencyDenomination": 100,
    "NoofCurrency": 2,
    "Total": "200.00",
    "IsNote": true
}, {
    "PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID": 5,
    "CurrencyDenomination": 50,
    "NoofCurrency": 2,
    "Total": "100.00",
    "IsNote": true
}, {
    "PK_MasterCurrencyDenomID": 6,
    "CurrencyDenomination": 20,
    "NoofCurrency": 2,
    "Total": "40.00",
    "IsNote": true
}]
```

to do that I write bellow code ,and think this is not right way to do that there must be some smart way to do that .Please suggest me a better alternative.

```
JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);
List<MasterCurrencyDenomination> d = new List<MasterCurrencyDenomination>();
string strjson = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in jsonArray.Children())
{

strjson+= item["CurrencyDenomination_JSON"].ToString().Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ",");

}

d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterCurrencyDenomination>>("["+strjson+"]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you observe the `Json`, it is evident that it is an `Array` of Type which contains a single `String` Property `CurrencyDenomination_JSON`. The Value of CurrencyDenomination_JSON is a **JSON string.**

What you need to do is, fetch these JSON strings  (represented as `IEnumerable<string>`), retrieve `JObject` from them by parsing each of them and Serialize the collection.

```
var currencyArray = JArray.Parse(json).Children<JObject>()
                     .SelectMany(x=>x.Properties().Select(c=>c.Value.Value<string>()));

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currencyArray.SelectMany(x=>JArray.Parse(x)));
```

Comment: Thanks ,works fine .if you don't mind can you please describe the logic for en-reaching knowledge.

Comment: @kuntal I have updated the answer with description, please do let me know if your need further explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use the following code to do this.

```
   List<MasterCurrencyDenomination> items = new List<MasterCurrencyDenomination>();

        JToken.Parse(myJson).ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            items.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterCurrencyDenomination>>(x.SelectToken("CurrencyDenomination_JSON").Value<string>()));
        });
```

OR:

```
        List<MasterCurrencyDenomination> items2 = new List<MasterCurrencyDenomination>();

        foreach (var test in JToken.Parse(myJson))
        {
            items2.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterCurrencyDenomination>>(test.SelectToken("CurrencyDenomination_JSON").Value<string>()));
        }
```